# Origine et raison du sens de « fouille-moi » pour « je ne sais pas » au Québec ?

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques, québec, origine-ou-raison, régionalismes

> Il tire une flûte de son sac d’école, il se trémousse pour faire oublier qu’il joue comme un pied, et [fouille-moi](https://oreilletendue.com/2022/10/05/au-corps/) pourquoi, les clients se ruent dans sa direction (*les Aurores montréales*, p. 77-78).

> Où va l'Homme? [Fouille](https://usito.usherbrooke.ca/d%C3%A9finitions/fouille-moi#fe8040ae583f863b)-moi (*La Presse*, 1993)

L'expression *fouille-moi* signifie « je ne sais pas/j’ignore de quoi il s’agit » en français familier du Québec (Usito).

- Comment en arrive-t-on à ce sens-là et quelle en est l'origine ?

Comment: Peut-être c'est un calque de l'anglais "[search me](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/search%20me)"?

Comment: @PeterShor C'est bien possible, tu peux évoquer cette possibilité dans une réponse et l'origine slang/1900 avec le sens sous-jacent évoqué [ici](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/search+me) re: Ammer.